# assertion failed: An outlet (menu) was specified but this view will render at the root level

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have this weird assertion error when I was rendering an extra outlet on the root level of my application.

This is the code I use:

```
<div id="app">
   <nav>{{outlet "menu"}}</nav>
   <div class="content">{{outlet}}</div>
</div>
```

I have a template called `menu`. This is my App.ApplicationRout

```
app.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render();
        this.render("menu", {
            outlet: "menu"
        });
    }
});
```

But it is throwing an error: `assertion failed: An outlet (menu) was specified but this view will render at the root level`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem, at root level you should pass the `into`-property in the `render`-function:

```
app.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render("menu", {
            outlet: "menu",
            into: 'application'
        });
        return this._super.apply(this,arguments);
    }
});
```

Now it renders just fine.

Comment: I tried this, and it works for me too.  Thanks!  What is the "into" property expected to specify?  The root template where to look for the "menu" outlet? It is surprising that there's no mention of "into" here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/.

Comment: Has been added with some explanations http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/