# Default outlet in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Today , I just start learning ember.js. I tried one sample application.

Search the result and it will show the list. Click on the link and it will show the result at right sidebar. It's working fine.

However, I want to show **home** template at first.

When I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116634/assertion-failed-an-outlet-menu-was-specified-but-this-view-will-render-at-th) with `{{outlet name}}` , it can show the home template however it is not working when I click on link. So, is there any way to show default outlet ?

I found about default outlet at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046193/ember-js-default-template-to-render-into-an-outlet) . However, it need to remove my data-templte-name to show default outlet. I don't want to remove the data-template-name.

Current template is like following.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dictionary">

    <div id="left">
        <header>
            <div id="topheader">
                <img src="images/logo.jpg" class="logo">
                <i id="search-icon">&nbsp;</i>
               {{input type="text" id="query" placeholder="Search"  value=query
               action="query"}}
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="results">
                {{#each results}}
              {{#link-to "detail" this}}
                  <section>
                <div class='detail'>
                <div class='word'>{{Word}}</div>
                <div class='state'>{{state}}</div>
                <div class='def'>{{def}}</div>
                </div>
                </section>
               {{/link-to}}
                {{/each}}
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div id="bottom">
                <a href="#" class='btn'>Login</a>
                <a href="#" class='btn add'>Add</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
     <div id="right">
     {{outlet}}
     </div>


</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="detail">
    <div id="details">
          <div class='word'>{{Word}}</div>
          <div class='state'>{{state}}</div>
          <div class='def'>{{def}}</div>
    </div>
    <div id="discuss">
    </div>

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="home">
  <div id="homeScreen">
        Sample home screen

  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root template to be rendered is the `application` template (associated with the root/application level).  An empty `id`/`data-template-name` is assumed to be the `application` template.  If you want to use a different template for the application root you can create the application view and specify the `templateName`.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'foo'
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EZocURAR/1/edit

Comment: Thank you but it's not working well after I put the Router.map for controller. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EZocURAR/3/edit

Comment: Application is always going to be the root of your ember application, but if you're going to make foo show up at the root path you should create an empty application template with an outlet.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EZocURAR/5/edit

Comment: thank you but your example is not showing the index template when page load

Comment: I got it http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nivoq/1/edit . However, I need to change the template name to index